# Overflow-y: auto on parent element hides child with position fixed

Tags: html, css, safari, overflow, css-position

In Safari, when a parent element has `overflow-y` set to `auto`, it treats `overflow-x` as `scroll` or `visible` when a child element has a position fixed. Is there a work around for this? Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt1cweyx/1/)

```
.flyout{
    position: fixed;
    //this doesnt display
}

.parent{
    overflow-y: auto
}
```

The flyout element is not visible in safari, while it is still visible in chrome, and firefox

Comment: So, I understand your question but I have to ask: Why are you using position: fixed in this case? Position: fixed is intended to be used to position an element relative to the viewport (window). If this is the case, why would it matter that it is a child of anything? If you intend to use position: fixed, take it out of the container. If you want to position it relative to the container, use position: absolute instead.

Comment: Just a note that you may have to change your design if you're attempting what I think you're attempting due to a quirk with overflow in the W3C spec. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue, and it really becomes a problem when attempting to add/remove fixed position based on breakpoints in responsive for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/magicdawn/vt1cweyx/10/

- remove `overflow` related from wrapper
- add `height` & `overflow-y` to a direct child

Since `overflow-x: visible` and `overflow-y: scroll` behaves strange in safari, so we split them to 2 elements.

- the top wrapper `.parent` handles `overflow-x: visible`
- inner element `.menu` handles `overflow-y: scroll`